# Strong maximum principle

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, maximum-principle, proof-explanation

Let $S^{n-1}$ denote sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $D$ denote open unit disk in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $f$ be homeomorphism of $S^{n-1}$ onto itself. Let $F$ be its harmonic extension given by Poisson integral. Then the result it to prove that $F$ is also an onto map. In the first part of it the result says to assume WLOG, that for $x\in{D}$ $F_1(x)=|F(x)|,F_2(x)=0,\ldots,F_n(x)=0$. Clearly this can be done by postrotating both $F$ and $f$. But then it says that by strong maximum principle, $F_1(x)<\max f_1=1$, so we get that image is contained in $D$. Can anyone tell me what this strong maximum priciple is?\ And secondly if we take $y\in{D\setminus F(D)}$, then the map $\psi$ defined on $S^{n-1}$ as $$\psi(x)=\frac{f(x)-y}{|f(x)-y|}.$$ How is this map one-one? Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Maximus or Maximum? I think the former was a Roman general or something. :-)

Comment: sorry typo error :)

Comment: Oh, that's a shame. I think that there was probably a "Strong Maximus principle" in the Roman tradition or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terminology of the "strong maximum principle" is not universal, but from the context, it is the form of the maximum principle that asserts that a non-constant harmonic function $h$ on a bounded domain $U$ that has a continuous extension to $\overline{U}$ satisfies the strict inequality

$$\lvert h(x)\rvert < \max \left\{\lvert h(y) \rvert : y \in \partial U\right\}$$

for every $x\in U$, where the non-strong maximum principle only asserts that

$$\max \left\{\lvert h(x)\rvert : x \in \overline{U}\right\} = \max \left\{\lvert h(y) \rvert : y \in \partial U\right\}$$

for any $h$ that is harmonic in $U$ and continuous on $\overline{U}$. Or maybe the strong maximum principle is stated in a different but equivalent formulation, like that a harmonic function that has a local maximum in $U$ is constant. Both possible versions of the "strong maximum principle" are often just called the "maximum principle" and no "strong maximum principle" is posited.

Regarding the second point, the injectivity of $\psi$ follows from the injectivity of $f$ and the fact that every ray emanating from $y\in D$ intersects the unit sphere $S^{n-1}$ in exactly one point (due to the strict convexity of $D$).

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful explanation for the second part. But i am doubtful about strict conevexity. what do we mean by strict convexity? i have studied convexity. And how is it being used here?

Comment: Strict convexity just means the boundary doesn't contain any line segments. Actually, we don't need the "strict" part here, the plain convexity is sufficient. Suppose there were a ray emanating from $y$ that intersected the boundary in (at least) two points. Use the fact that $y$ is in the interior of $D$ to derive a contradiction. Then see what $\psi(x_1) = \psi(x_2)$ would entail for $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$.

Comment: for any $x\in{S^{n-1}}$, $y-f(x)$ actually lies on the ray from $y$ and passing through $f(x)$, and this function $\psi$ brings it back to sphere (normalising). and since $y$ is in interior of $D$, we get that $\psi$ is injective. is this correct?

Comment: Yes, $\psi(x_1) = \psi(x_2)$ if and only if $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$ lie on the same ray. Since $f\colon S^{n-1}\to S^{n-1}$, that means $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$. And hence by the injectivity of $f$ it follows that $x_1 = x_2$.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Comment: can we prove surjectivity of $\psi$ too?

Comment: Sure. Let $\xi \in S^{n-1}$. Consider the ray $y + t\xi,\; t \in [0,\infty)$. It intersects $S^{n-1}$ in $p_\xi = y + t_0\xi$ for some $t_0 \in (0,2)$. Then, since $f$ is a homeomorphism (we use the surjectivity), $p_\xi = f(x_\xi)$, and that means $\psi(x_\xi) = \xi$.